# plot solution of fsolve() of parametric function

Tags: plot, maple

I have a function `f(v,u)` and I defined function

```
solutionf(u) := fsolve(f(v,u)=v);
```

I need to plot `solutionf(u)` depending on `u` but just

```
plot(solutionf(u), u = 0 .. 0.4e-1)
```

gives me an error

```
Error, (in fsolve) number of equations, 1, does not match number of variables, 2
```

However I can always take the value `solutionf(x)` at any `x`.

Is there simple way to plot this? Or I have to make own `for` loop over `u`, take value at every point and plot interploating values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the most-often-asked Maple questions. Your error is caused by what is known as *premature evaluation*, the expression **solutionf(u)** being evaluated before **u** has been given a numeric value.

There are several ways to avoid premature evaluation. The simplest is probably to use forward single quotes:

**plot('solutionf(u)', u= 0..0.4e-1);**

Comment: Thanks! I just found also solution as `plot(solutionf, 0..0.4e-1)` but I see your version as better one.

Comment: The solution that you mentioned is what I personally would usually use. The use of quotes, especially when they're nested, can lead to some paradoxical situations.